# Big O-Notation of N-Dimensional array

Tags: c++, big-o

What is the complexity of the two algorithms below (`size` is the length of each dimension)?:

```
void a(int** arr, int size) {
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            arr[i][j] += 1;
        }
    }
    print(arr, size);
}

void b(int*** arr, int size) {
    int m = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
            {
               arr[i][j][k] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    print(arr, size);
}
```

I believe the first function is `O(N^2)` and the second function is `O(N^3)`. Is this right?
For any `N-D` array of `N` size I am saying the complexity will be `N!`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Time Complexity :

- The time complexity of first function is - `O(size^2)`
- The time complexity of second function is - `O(size^3)`
- The time complexity of N-dimensional array each of size `N` for a similar function would be - `O(N^N)` since the iterations required would be N * N * N... upto N times.

---

So, you were correct in the first two - `O(N^2)` and `O(N^3)` if by `N` you meant `size`. The last statement, however, was incorrect. `N!` grows slower than `N^N` and hence the `N!` as the upper bound would be wrong. It should be `O(N^N)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the first function is O(N^2) and the second function is O(N^3). Is this right?

Yes, it is N * N for the first, and N * N * N for the second

> For any N-D array of N size I am saying the complexity will be N!. Is this correct?

Not exactly. The complexity will be N^N (N to the Nth power), which is higher

N^N = N * N * .... * N

N! = N * (N - 1) * ... * 1

(To find the ratio between the two, you can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), incidentally.)

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that big-O notation is only relevant when relative to an actual frame. If a multi-dimensional array is considered all elements of data, and each element is visited once in an algorithm -- then the complexity would generally be considered O(N) -- even if N is actually O(size * size * ... * size), since each dimension is part of N overall inputs that get visited.

Comment: @Human-Compiler It was stated that `N` is the size in each direction. It would be misleading to give a result where `N` refers to something else (e,g, the total size, as you suggest).

Comment: Technically the question is stated that `size` is the length of _each dimension_, but not of the length of the overall input. The notation `O(N^2)` for visiting all elements of a 2-d array once is only applicable if the `N` we refer to _is_ `size`. That's all I meant. Otherwise, the big-O notation of visiting all elements of a multidimensional array once would generally be considered `O(N)`, which could be expanded to `O(size1 * size2 * ...)` or `O(size ^ d)` if all dimensions are the same size.

Comment: @Human-Compiler *"Technically the question is stated that size is the length of each dimension, but not of the length of the overall input."* -- yes, and it goes on to say "of `N` size".  So `N` is the size, and the size is length of each dimension, hence `N` is the length in each dimension. Also, `N` is the size, and the size is not the length of the overall input, so `N` is not the length of the overall input. Yet you suggest re-defining `N` to mean the length of the overall input.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the first function is `O(N^2)` and the second function is `O(N^3)`. Is this right?
>   For any `N-D` array of `N` size I am saying the complexity will be `N!`. Is this correct?

I think you skipped an important step in your analysis. You started by looking at two sample cases (2-D and 3-D). So far, so good. You analyzed the complexity in those two cases, deciding the 2-D case is `O(N^2)` and the 3-D is `O(N^3)`. Also good. But then you skipped a step.

The next step should be to generalize to arbitrary dimension `D`. You looked at two sample cases, you see the `2` and the `3` appearing in the formulas, so it is reasonable to theorize that you can replace that with `D`. The theory is that for an array of dimension `D`, the complexity is `O(N^D)`. Ideally you do some more work to either prove this or at least check that it holds in a case you have not looked at yet, like 4-D. Once you have confidence in this result, you are ready to move on.

It is only after getting the formula for a the arbitrary dimension case that you should specialize to the case where the dimension equals the size. This result is rather easy, as assuming `D == N` means it is valid to replace `D` with `N` in your formula; the complexity is `O(N^N)`.

Comment: Nice explanation